# Azure Pipeline to build docker images fails using same docker file in Visual Studio

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to create a deployment pipeline to deploy my image to Kubernetes cluster.  The first step in this process is to create an image based on the docker file.  The docker file I'm using was generated from Visual Studio when I added docker support and successfully creates the image when right clicking on the docker image and selecting to create it.  When I configure the Azure Pipeline, the create docker image fails as soon as it tries to build the actual solution.  The previous step grabs all the sources files but then fails on the docker image creation with

```
[error]COPY failed: stat/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder158012929/DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj:
 no such file or directory

[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1
```

The following is the docker file generated from Visual studio and is referenced by the azure pipeline stage to create the docker image.

```
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-stretch-slim AS base

 WORKDIR /app   
 FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS
 build 

 WORKDIR /src      
 COPY ["DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj", "DockerTest/"]      
 RUN dotnet restore "DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj"      
 COPY . .      
 WORKDIR "/src/DockerTest"      
 RUN dotnet build "DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app  

 FROM build AS publish      
 RUN dotnet publish "DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

 FROM base AS final      
 WORKDIR /app      
 COPY --from=publish /app .      
 ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerTest.dll"]
```

[image]

> ##[section]Starting: Build a container image
>   ============================================================================== Task: Docker Description : Build, tag, push, or run Docker images, or
>   run a Docker command. Task can be used with Docker or Azure Container
>   registry. Version : 0.150.6  Author : Microsoft Corporation Help :
>   [More Information]https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=848006)
>   ============================================================================== [command]/usr/bin/docker build -f
>   /home/vsts/work/1/s/DockerTest/Dockerfile -t 
>   ihacontainers.azurecr.io/dockertest:6 /home/vsts/work/1/s/DockerTest 
>   Sending build context to Docker daemon  6.144kB     Step 1/15 : FROM 
>   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
>   2.2-stretch-slim: Pulling from dotnet/core/runtime 743f2d6c1f65: Pulling fs layer 074da88b8de0: Pulling fs layer ac831735b47a: Pulling 
>   fs layer 3adcc844418d: Pulling fs layer 3adcc844418d: Waiting 
>   ac831735b47a: Download complete 743f2d6c1f65: Verifying Checksum 
>   743f2d6c1f65: Download complete 074da88b8de0: Verifying Checksum 
>   074da88b8de0: Download complete 3adcc844418d: Verifying Checksum 
>   zadcc844418d: Download complete 743f2d6c1f65: Pull complete 
>   074da88b8de0: Pull complete ac831735b47a: Pull complete 3adcc844418d: 
>   Pull complete Digest: 
>   sha256:066c31b113b0a20e6155d3bd8a314563c688d2ec31c11d7e551af5bc2595f30c
>   Status: Downloaded newer image for 
>   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime:2.2-stretch-slim  ---> 
>   c0f9ab44ecc1 Step 2/15 : WORKDIR /app  ---> Running in 6d1a5f5600dd 
>   Removing intermediate container 6d1a5f5600dd  ---> 527fcebeaf1f Step 
>   3/15 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
>   2.2-stretch: Pulling from dotnet/core/sdk c5e155d5a1d1: Pulling fs layer 221d80d00ae9: Pulling fs layer 4250b3117dca: Pulling fs layer 
>   3b7ca19181b2: Pulling fs layer 3466298fc231: Pulling fs layer 
>   310737d73ed1: Pulling fs layer dc981de74fae: Pulling fs layer 
>   3b7ca19181b2: Waiting 3466298fc231: Waiting 310737d73ed1: Waiting 
>   dc981de74fae: Waiting 4250b3117dca: Verifying Checksum 4250b3117dca: 
>   Download complete 221d80d00ae9: Verifying Checksum 221d80d00ae9: 
>   Download complete 3466298fc231: Verifying Checksum 3466298fc231: 
>   Download complete c5e155d5a1d1: Verifying Checksum c5e155d5a1d1: 
>   Download complete 3b7ca19181b2: Verifying Checksum 3b7ca19181b2: 
>   Download complete c5e155d5a1d1: Pull complete 221d80d00ae9: Pull 
>   complete 310737d73ed1: Verifying Checksum 310737d73ed1: Download 
>   complete 4250b3117dca: Pull complete dc981de74fae: Verifying Checksum 
>   dc981de74fae: Download complete 3b7ca19181b2: Pull complete 
>   3466298fc231: Pull complete 310737d73ed1: Pull complete dc981de74fae: 
>   Pull complete Digest: 
>   sha256:222cc0bb0bc93875ee0f6be626b2838beea838f65e53653e07c33eb9d00b0163
>   Status: Downloaded newer image for
>   mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch  ---> e4747ec2aaff Step 
>   4/15 : WORKDIR /src  ---> Running in a7ebcac87f68 Removing 
>   intermediate container a7ebcac87f68  ---> d7541674a9da Step 5/15 : 
>   COPY ["DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj", "DockerTest/"] COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder158012929/DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj:no
>   such file or directory
>
> **##[error]COPY failed: stat/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder158012929/DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj:no
>   such file or directory**
>
> **##[error]/usr/bin/docker failed with return code: 1  ##[section]Finishing: Build a container image**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> [error]COPY failed: stat/var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder158012929/DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj: no such file or directory

According to this error message, the error occurred on the line of your dockerfile:              `COPY ["DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj", "DockerTest/"]`.

First, please confirm that you did not use `.dockerignore` file to exclude this file: `DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj`, which must exists in the directory where you run your build from.

If it does not ignored by `.dockerignore` file, then you need to consider about your dockerfile location level.

`DockerTest.csproj` file should not put at the lower source file path level. You need to change the source of the context, move it at a higher level. So modify your dockerfile manually as :

```
COPY ["DockerTest.csproj", "DockerTest/"]
```

Comment: So that did get me past the first error, but now it complains that about it not having a suitable static main entry point when running the following command  (which of course it does).    RUN dotnet build "DockerTest.csproj" -c Release -o /app

Comment: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [/src/DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj]

Comment: One other side effect is that now building the docker image from Visual Studio locally fails since we changed the location.  Maybe there is a way to set the correct location from the build pipeline when getting source code, so I don't have to modify the dockerfile.

Comment: Do you also change the location of DockerTest.csproj file locally while you modefy the docker file？

Comment: Actually I think I fixed it and allowed it to work from either location.  I reverted back to the original dockerfile that studio generated and then I unchecked the "Use Default Build Context" on the build image task followed by clearing the folder it had listed which was "DockerTest".  Now the whole thing completes from azure and locally.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Awesome！Glad to hear that :-) It’s also my pleasure can give you some help.

Comment: The latest comment of @Geekn fixed the issue for me (Uncheck Use Default Build Context). 
It should be added as answer and marked as the best answer!

Answer (score 39):

I solved the issue by setting the buildContext to '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)' using the same dockerfile as in Visual Studio without adjusting the paths:

In YAML-Konfiguration, I added the following line:

```
buildContext: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Pipelines is by default running the command in the directory where the Dockerfile lives (which is at the project level), whereas Visual Studio runs it at the Repository/Solution level

Comment: This worked for me too.. make sure you put it in your yaml file under Settings: Inputs (on azure anyway). I also struggled with this locally. But the result is the same.. specify the relative path to your dockerfile or to the root

Comment: You can also use buildContext: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)', as $(Build.SourcesDirectory) is synonymous to $(Build.Repository.LocalPath).
See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables

Answer (score 9):

This problem is arise when you generate the Docker support via Visual Studio (v16.3.9 at least) and you are using this generated project in the Azure Pipeline with the predefined Docker pipeline template either in old-fashioned everything-to-click way so called **the classic editor** or the new 4-step easy-to-click way so called **the modern editor**.

The change in the generated file from

```
COPY ["DockerTest/DockerTest.csproj", "DockerTest/"]
```

to

```
COPY ["DockerTest.csproj", "DockerTest/"]
```

solve the problem with the Azure Pipeline but it **will break** your local build within the Visual Studio.

Adding

```
buildContext: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'
```

to the YAML file which has been generated by the modern editor will break the build task. The template which is used in the modern editor relies on the default build context and the parser **will not recognise** the `buildContext` command.

[image: YAML file from the new editor]

Only possible way how to fix this problem is  **to override the default build context**. This override will keep the build functionality either in Visual Studio or the Azure Pipeline.

The build context can be overridden in the build image task in the classic editor.

[image: Fixing the build problem in the build image task.]

Comment: the 'unexpected property buildContext' error you're seeing here is due to incorrect indentation of the property. It needs to be indented to the same level as the 'command' property

Comment: @JeffreyABecker Actually, it was an issue in the YAML parser. If I tried to update file manually, the parser would let me because the parser would recognise a line with the build context no matter where I put it. If I used the task web form, everything was OK.

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked with following yaml settings

steps:

- task: Docker@2

  displayName: Build docker

  inputs:

  command: 'buildAndPush'

  Dockerfile: '**/Dockerfile'

  buildContext: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)'

The dockerfile can stay as Visual Studio generated it.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the following folder structure:

```
+-- [REPOSITORY FOLDER]
|   +-- [SOLUTION FOLDER]
|   |   +-- [*.SLN]
|   |   +-- [PROJECT Folder]
|   |   |   +-- [*.CSPROJ]
|   |   |   +-- [dockerfile]
```

My docker file is inside the project folder.
After modifying to use only the CSPROJ file in the first copy, and receiving the missing MAIN method error, not having a suitable static main entry point, I fixed it replacing the "copy .." to "COPY . [project_name]/"

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["SampleApi1.csproj", "SampleApi1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "SampleApi1/SampleApi1.csproj"
COPY . SampleApi1/
WORKDIR "/src/SampleApi1"
RUN dotnet build "SampleApi1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "SampleApi1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "SampleApi1.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your Dockerfile to the root, alongside the .sln file.

None of the other answers worked for me, it would never find the project paths to the csproj files.

My project only contains one project that needs to be containerized, and some support dll projects, so I moved the original Dockerfile created by Visual Studio into the root, alongside the .sln file, and our pipeline built the image and deployed it to our ACR no problem.

I think the other solutions, if they work for you, are better, but if not, and it will work in your situation, give this a shot.