# .NetCore microservice CI pipeline Azure DevOps Build error @ docker image

Tags: docker, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am very much new on docker technology, I am getting the build error while creating the .Net Core 3.1 on Azure DevOps CI pipeline on Docker image tasks:

> Step 7/17 : COPY ["API2/API2.csproj", "API2/"] COPY failed: CreateFile
>   \?\C:\ProgramData\docker\tmp\docker-builder021493529\API2\API2.csproj:
>   The system cannot find the path specified.

My default docker file is

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS base 
WORKDIR /app 
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-nanoserver-1809 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["API1/API1.csproj", "API1/"]
RUN dotnet restore "API1/API1.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/API1"
RUN dotnet build "API1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "API1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final 
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "API1.dll"]
```

Please do let me know from where I am doing mistake.

Here are the docker tasks:

[image]

Here are the folder and files structure on azure DevOps as well:

[image: file structure]

Comment: Can you share your Docker build task in Azure DevOps?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Please  find the images pasted on question section

Comment: Why do you use task version `0`?

Comment: there is no specific reason i can use 2.* as well, but as per point now i used  2.* version but still facing the same issue

Comment: In version 2 which value do you have in the Context field?.

Comment: I am putting Context Build value $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> COPY ["API1/API1.csproj", "API1/"]

Based on the error message, this should the line that caused the error message.

**Step1:**

Please ensure you did not configure the `.dockerignore` file to exclude this file: `API1/API1.csproj`, which must exists in the directory where you run your build from.

**Step2:**

After above confirmed, now we can consider the error is caused about the server could not find the `csproj` file correctly by following the context and the path you provided.

---

According to the your original definition: `API1/API1.csproj`, I guess the actual path of `API1.csproj` in your repository should be `src/API1/API1.csproj`, right?

If yes, here has 2 method you can try:

**1).** Change the `COPY` definition as:

```
    COPY ["API1.csproj", "API1/"]
```

***Updated:***

When you apply this method, you may succeed to COPY, but failed with `Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point *****`.

Here it means that the `COPY . .` does not copy the files correctly.

At this time, please also change the `COPY . .` to `COPY . API1/`. This will **add folder to dest path**.

**2).** Another way is you could specify `API1` to `Build context` in task:

Below is what I am using, and I do not need make any changes into my `dockerfile`:

you can input `$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)` by replacing hard code the context:

[image]

***Updated:***

In Docker 2.*, you can also leave **Build context** to `**`:

[image]

You can refer to my previous answer on such question: [#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56389748/11508165).

---

*Based on my opinions, I am not recommend the first method I mentioned above, because it let your `dockerfile` different with the one which you can run successfully in Visual studio.*

Comment: thanks @Merlin for posting the detail reply to my query: well I go for 1st step and i changed COPY ["API2.csproj", "API2/"] , now build proceed to next level and now i am facing another error 
Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point [C:\src\API2\API2.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)"

Comment: @SaadAwan, Okay, this is what I do not want you faced. Please change the line 9 to `COPY . API1/` to add folder to dest path.  As I suggest in my answer, I strongly suggest you use the second method which do not need make changes into dockerfile. In addition, here I have the same puzzle with shayki, why not use `docker 2.*` task? Any trouble with that?

Comment: now i am using docker tasks 2.* and add the brand new docker file which vs 2019 created, and add build context $(Build.Repository.LocalPath), but still same result API2\API2.csproj: The system cannot find the path specified

Comment: @SaadAwan. For CI, it is by default running the docker in the directory where the dockerfile lives which is at the project level, but VS runs it at the Repos/Solution level. How's your file structure? That's why here you can input $(Build.Repository.LocalPath). Not sure why this is not suitable for you (on my side it is work fine), please make the context to `**` and build again. I update my answer to make it more clear. You can check it.

Comment: @SaadAwan, https://filebin.net/ofx8y31wmpn6tv5n/dockerfile.txt?t=w8g9rpqh This is the dockerfile which I modified based on your dockerfile. **Note** the order of `WORKDIR /src/TestWebApp` and `COPY . .`, this way could let you avoid the error of `Program does not contain a static 'Main' method`. And for docker 2.* task, you do not need change any default value, just like this: https://imgur.com/a/k7jvnfo  This is the **solution 1** I mentioned in my answer. And different with my answer, here I change the order of **COPY** and **WORKDIR**, then you don't need change the `COPY . .`

Comment: Thanks @Merlin you provided detailed answer of my query, I have created another clean project and apply docker Version 2.* Docker Context ="$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)" and its works for me and my image tasks passes and image went on to ACR.                                                              
Thanks once again for the help you saved my life.