# VS 2019 Container Application for Kubernetes errors received when deploying with Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, containers, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-2019

I created a Container Application for Kubernetes in Visual Studio as follows:

[image]

Docker file looks like this:

[image]

Result from running in Powershell with success:

[image]

I tried using the pipeline template - Deploy to Azure Kubernetes Service:

[image]

I used the YAML "as-is":

[image]

When I save and run, I get the following:

[image]

### [error]COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder947419078/KubeApp/KubeApp.csproj: no such file or directory

### [error]The process '/usr/bin/docker' failed with exit code 1

Please advise

Comment: May I know how's the status on this issue? Did you get any help with my suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

> [error]COPY failed: stat
>   /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder947419078/KubeApp/KubeApp.csproj: no
>   such file or directory

The cause of this error is actually due to the different execution mechanisms between **pipeline** and **local** when running the dockerfile.

For `pipeline`, it is by default running the docker in the directory where the dockerfile lives which is at the **project level**, but `VS/local` runs it at the **Repos/Solution level**.

So, to solve this issue, you can try with below method

Change the `COPY` definition as:

```
    COPY ["KubeApp.csproj", "KubeApp/"]
```

This method can let you succeed to `COPY`, but failed with `Program does not contain a static 'Main' method`.

At this time:

- One way is change the `COPY . .`(L10) to `COPY . KubeApp/`. This will
  **add folder to dest path**.
- Or, you can change the order of `COPY`(L10) and `WORKDIR`(L11) without change the `COPY . .`.

---

*See my previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59530808/netcore-microservice-ci-pipeline-azure-devops-build-error-docker-image/59533103#59533103) that others solved the same issue by applying my suggestion.*