# .csproj file not found when building docker image using Azure Pipeline

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, dockerfile, azure-pipelines

## My goal

I want to publish a docker image to Dockerhub from the Azure DevOps Pipeline.
The pipeline runs after a commit on the master branch in Gitlab.
The application I want to build an image for is a .Net Core Web API project.
I'm using the automatically created Dockerfile by dotnet.

## Error

This is the error I get:

[image]

## Information

The folder structure of my application looks like this:

```
 - APIGateway [Folder]
   - APIGateway [Folder]
     - Controller/Models/Services etc... [Folders]
     - APIGateway.csproj
     - APIGateway.csproj.user
     - **Dockerfile**
     - Program.cs
     - Startup.cs
     - Appsettings,json
     - Appsettings.Development.json
   - APIGateway.UnitTests [Folder]
   - .dockerignore
   - APIGateway.sln
 - Readme.md
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

[image]

For the Azure Pipeline, I added the .Net Core template task (restore, build, test, publish, publish artifect) to the agent job. The pipeline executes these tasks successfully.
I also added the Docker BuildAndPush task and configured my Dockerhub as a container registry.

The commands for the BuildAndPush task:

[image]

I already looked at this similar post: [Azure Pipeline to build docker images fails using same docker file in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56386812/azure-pipeline-to-build-docker-images-fails-using-same-docker-file-in-visual-stu). People mainly suggested to add 'Build.Repository.LocalPath' to the build context. But I still get the same error.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Does the container build locally? Based on the folder hierarchy you described, I can't see how it would.

Comment: No, I get the same error locally.

Comment: Okay, so you have a problem with your `dockerfile`. It has nothing to do with Azure DevOps. You need to fix the problem locally. Look at the directory hierarchy versus what the `dockerfile` says and the error message; it's telling you that it can't find a file. The docker context is, by default, the **folder that contains the dockerfile** and all of the subdirectories. You're already in the `APIGateway` folder, so your `COPY` command is pointing to a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: So now I got it working locally. I moved the Dockerfile one directory up and kept the Dockerfile the same. But the Azure Pipeline still gives the same error as described in my question...

Comment: It works now! Thx for the help @DanielMann

Comment: @YobBoy.  Glad to know that it could work now. You could share your solution in answer and accept it. This will be helpful to other users.

Comment: I have the same issue. Would you mind sharing your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Others have alluded to this in the comments.

Given you have a folder structure containing multiple projects within a solution similar to this:
[image]

AND your Dockerfile was created in one of the projects within the solution (e.g., the Server project) similar to this (e.g., generated by VS-right click, Add Docker support):

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Server/QuizManagerClientHosted.Server.csproj", "Server/"]
COPY ["Client/QuizManagerClientHosted.Client.csproj", "Client/"]
COPY ["Shared/QuizManagerClientHosted.Shared.csproj", "Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Server/QuizManagerClientHosted.Server.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Server"
RUN dotnet build "QuizManagerClientHosted.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "QuizManagerClientHosted.Server.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "QuizManagerClientHosted.Server.dll"]
```

Problem: It works locally but not via ADO (or perhaps GitHub Actions or other CI/CD solutions).
Solution: Move the Dockerfile up one level (e.g., from the Server directory to the QuizManagerClientHosted directory).